# Give a function $f$ with no limit at $0$ s.t.$ f: {\mathbb{R}}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{t \to 0} f(tv) = 0$ for every vector $v \neq 0$

Tags: calculus

Give a function $f: {\mathbb{R}}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. for every vector $v \neq 0$ $\lim_{t \to 0} f(tv) = 0$ but $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t)$ doesn't exist.

I thought about a function that is 0 in all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ except for a spiral that starts at $0$, where $f=1$. Would this work? How do I formally word this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} &\mbox{ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$} \\
0 &\mbox{ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}.
\end{cases}
$$

The point is to make $f$ converge to nonzero value along the curve $x=y^2$,
while it converges to $0$ on every line $y=kx$.